# How can I implement http-only cookie-JWT authentication using React and Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, cookies

I am new to programming and just started full-stack project with NodeJS and React. I read somewhere a while ago that saving JWT tokens inside http-only cookies is better in terms of security than just saving them in localstorage, so I decided to implement that, but don't know how.

This is my Login controller in express

```
const signIn = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any> => {
  const userEmail = req.body.email;
  const userPassword = req.body.password;

  const user: any = await User.findOne({ email: userEmail }).clone();

  const isValid = await user.comparePassword(userPassword);

  if (isValid) {
    const tokenObject = utils.issueJWT(user);
    res.cookie("jwt", tokenObject.token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: tokenObject.expiresIn,
    });
    res.send(tokenObject.token);
  } else
    res
      .status(401)
      .json({ success: false, msg: "You entered the wrong password" });
};
```

But I don't know how to access stored cookie with React and then authenticate user.

This is my Login component in React

```
import { SyntheticEvent, useState } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

function SignIn() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [navigate, setNavigate] = useState(false);

  const submit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await fetch("http://localhost:8080/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
      credentials: "include",
    });

    setNavigate(true);
  };

  if(navigate){
    return <Navigate to="/users"/>
  }

  return (
    <form action="/login" method="post" onSubmit={submit}>
      <div className="form-outline mb-4">
        <input
          type="email"
          id="form2Example1"
          className="form-control"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label className="form-label" htmlFor="form2Example1">
          Email address
        </label>
      </div>

      <div className="form-outline mb-4">
        <input
          type="password"
          id="form2Example2"
          className="form-control"
          name="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label className="form-label" htmlFor="form2Example2">
          Password
        </label>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4">
        Sign in
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default SignIn;
```

Token is really stored inside cookie if checked in inspect or POSTMAN:
[postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCiFL.png)

While I worked with EJS forms I had my personal implementation of verifying if the user was authenticated or not and it worked:

```
const verifyJWT = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const signedToken = req.cookies.jwt;

  if (signedToken) {
    jwt.verify(
      signedToken,
      config.PRIV_KEY,
      { algorithms: ["RS256"] },
      async (err: any, decodedToken: any) => {
        if (err) {
          // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
          console.log(decodedToken);
          next();
        }
      }
    );
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
};
```

Do I need to implement something similar to this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access httpOnly cookie in browser it is just send along to browser so it can then be used in the backend . You can access it in your backend app .
I mean if httpOnly cookie is accessed in browser than it is similar to localStorage . Learn to implement the accessToken and refreshToken approach  for Auethntication and authorization.

This is one example:

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens/#:~:text=Since%20access%20tokens%20aren't,in%20a%20very%20short%20duration](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens/#:%7E:text=Since%20access%20tokens%20aren%27t,in%20a%20very%20short%20duration).